Quarkus Rest Lambda fails on parsing HTTP2 pseudo headers
I've created a Quarkus Lambda using Quarkus Rest (https://quarkus.io/guides/aws-lambda-http). When I hit the lambda with a request, it will try to unmarshal and parse the AWS Lambda request event type.
Instead of using AWS APIGateway as an entrypoint into my Lambda, I use Gloo Gateway's Lambda integration: https://docs.solo.io/gloo-edge/main/guides/traffic_management/destination_types/aws_lambda/
When Gloo creates an AWS Lambda request event, it includes a number of HTTP2 pseudo headers, e.g.:
{
    "body": "",
    "headers": {
        ":authority": "lambda.example.com:81",
        ":method": "GET",
        ":path": "/hello",
        ":scheme": "http",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "user-agent": "curl/8.7.1",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
        "x-request-id": "76e5213d-4327-49ae-97b3-6a78099ca41b"
    },
    ....

Quarkus is however unable to validate these headers and fails on the first one (but I assume it will fail on the others as well):
2024-12-12 09:48:32,057 ERROR [qua.ama.lam.http] (main) Request Failure: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: a header name cannot contain some prohibited characters, such as : :authority
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpUtils.validateHeaderName0(HttpUtils.java:992)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpUtils.validateHeaderName(HttpUtils.java:964)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpUtils.validateHeader(HttpUtils.java:851)
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.QuarkusHttpHeaders.add0(QuarkusHttpHeaders.java:535)
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.QuarkusHttpHeaders.add(QuarkusHttpHeaders.java:90)
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.QuarkusHttpHeaders.add(QuarkusHttpHeaders.java:97)
at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.QuarkusHttpHeaders.add(QuarkusHttpHeaders.java:35)
at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.LambdaHttpHandler.nettyDispatch(LambdaHttpHandler.java:195)
at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.http.LambdaHttpHandler.handleRequest(LambdaHttpHandler.java:63)
...

Is this expected? Is there a way to allow Quarkus to handle HTTP2 pseudo-headers? Or is there a way to disable header validation in my Lambda (which is dangerous, I know)?
I've tried to disable HTTP header validation by configuring in my application.properties:
vertx.disableHttpHeadersValidation=true

But that didn't seem to have any effect, I still have the same problem. I've also tried to remove the HTTP2 pseudo headers on the gateway, but Gloo/Envoy does not allow me to do remove these specific headers.

According to the code itself, the variable is a JVM System property.  Not to be set in application.properties
  /** JVM system property that disables HTTP headers validation, don't use this in production. */
  private static final String DISABLE_HTTP_HEADERS_VALIDATION_PROP_NAME = "vertx.disableHttpHeadersValidation";


Also not sure of this since I have not tried it, but look into @ServerRequestFilter and see if you can modify/remove these headers before it hitting the handler method.
Examples of usage:
import java.util.Optional;

class Filters {

    @ServerRequestFilter(preMatching = true)
    public void preMatchingFilter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        // make sure we don't lose cheese lovers
        if("yes".equals(requestContext.getHeaderString("Cheese"))) {
            requestContext.setRequestUri(URI.create("/cheese"));
        }
    }

    @ServerRequestFilter
    public Optional<RestResponse<Void>> getFilter(ContainerRequestContext ctx) {
        // only allow GET methods for now
        if(!ctx.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.GET)) {
            return Optional.of(RestResponse.status(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}


Request filters are usually executed on the same thread that the
method that handles the request will be executed. That means that if
the method servicing the request is annotated with @Blocking, then the
filters will also be run on the worker thread. If the method is
annotated with @NonBlocking (or is not annotated at all), then the
filters will also be run on the same event-loop thread.
If however a filter needs to be run on the event-loop despite the fact
that the method servicing the request will be run on a worker thread,
then @ServerRequestFilter(nonBlocking=true) can be used. Note however,
that these filters need to be run before any filter that does not use
that setting and would run on a worker thread.
Keep in mind however that the information above does not apply to
pre-matching filters (@ServerRequestFilter(preMatching = true)). These
filters are always run on an event-loop thread.

https://quarkus.io/guides/rest#request-or-response-filters

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73531939/using-reactive-serverrequestfilter-with-restclient-in-quarkus
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76822196/decorating-all-resteasy-reactive-request-handling-in-quarkus-amazon-lambda-http
